# How to join data from 2 tables in stored procedure into 1 result set?

Tags: mysql

With mysql 8 I need to join data from 2 tables Branches and Departments tables into 1 result set with fields like

- `id` - id of a Branch or Department table
- `name` - name of a Branch or Department table
- `parent_id` - is null for Branches and not null for Departments

In this way I need data for tree data with  - id of a Branch(1st level) or Department(2nd level) table.

I try to join it in a procedure with 2 cursors and 1 temporary table, like :

```
create procedure getBranchesWithDepartments(IN in_branchId smallint unsigned)
BEGIN


    DECLARE branchId smallint unsigned;
    DECLARE branchName varchar(100);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE branchesCursor cursor for SELECT branches.id, branches.name -- 1st cursor
                                      FROM branches
                                      WHERE branches.active = 1
                                        AND (in_branchId IS NULL OR branches.id = in_branchId)
                                      ORDER BY branches.id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    DECLARE departmentsCursor cursor for SELECT id, name -- 2nd cursor for any found branch
                            FROM departments
                            WHERE branch_id = :branchId   -- How to get reference to branches.id from above cursor
                                      ORDER BY name;
-- In which way have I to declare CONTINUE HANDLER for 2nd cursor?
-- DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BranchesWithDepartmentsTable
    (
        id        bigint unsigned,
        name      varchar(100),
        parent_id bigint unsigned
    );

    DELETE FROM BranchesWithDepartmentsTable;

    open branchesCursor;
    branchesLoop:
    loop
        fetch branchesCursor into branchId, branchName;
        INSERT INTO BranchesWithDepartmentsTable SELECT branchId, branchName, null;

        open departmentsCursor; -- But how to pass branches.id parameter from cursor above ?
        fetch departmentsCursor into branchId, branchName; -- internal cursor

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE branchesLoop;
        END IF;

    end loop branchesLoop;
    close branchesCursor;

    SELECT branchId, branchName, parent_id from BranchesWithDepartmentsTable;

END;
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add sample data an desired outcome as text.

Comment: Aside: `TRUNCATE tablename` is generally better than `DELETE FROM tablename` when you want to clear out the table.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `JOIN` query?

Comment: Actually, I think what you're actually looking for is `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just be a `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, name, NULL AS parent_id
FROM branches
WHERE branches.active = 1
AND (in_branchId IS NULL OR id = in_branchId)
ORDER BY id

UNION ALL

SELECT id, name, branch_id
FROM departments
WHERE (in_branchId IS NULL OR branch_id = in_branchId)
ORDER BY name
```